# How to boot an Ubuntu 20.04 Live version with WDS?

Tags: windows

I managed to configure my WDS (working on a Windows Server 2016) so it can boot Windows and Ubuntu System via PXE. This is working fine but I can only install Ubuntu and not access the live version before the installation, the installation menu does not provides any access to a live version and I need an access to it before the install.

Does anyone have an idea on how to proceed ?

For information, I use a netboot iso file for booting the Ubuntu .

Comment: The netboot ISO has no live environment. Only Ubuntu desktop has it.

Comment: Do you think Is it possible to modify the netboot ISO and to add a live environment in it ?

Comment: No, I don't think so.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your answer. I will try anyway and will let you know if i am successfull